# Comparing a variable/string with an array

Tags: php, string-comparison

I have a database which records the values of previously selected items in a multi select dropdown.

The update form selects the values for the dropdown and then I am trying to show the previously chosen options as 'selected'

snippet of code

```
$speclist = '2, 3, 171, 172';
$result = db_query("SELECT `specid` FROM `specialities` ORDER BY `specname` ASC");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $specid = $row['specid'];
          $selected1 = '';
          if (strpos($speclist, $specid) !== false) {
              $selected1 = " selected='selected'";
          }
          echo "<option value='" . $specid . "'".$selected1.">" . $row['specname'] . "</option>";
          $selected1 = '';
      }
```

However, the `selected1` variable is being written if the specid is 2, 12, 22, 32, 13, 23 etc etc

If speclist only contains 172 it is selecting 2, 17, 72 and 172

How can I do it so that it adds `selected` on exact matches, and not the other variants?

I know I'm probably trying to find a match the wrong way but can't find a solution.

Comment: Change `$speclist ` to an array and use `in_array`... or you could parse that as a CSV and then compare but seems like more work.

Comment: You can use `explode()` to convert the string into an array.

Comment: If the previous selections are in the database, why don't you have the query return whether the option was previously selected, instead of using `$speclist`?